# How to reconcile that there are seven earths with the verses that Allah "created the heavens and the earth"?

Tags: tafseer, contradiction

> Surely your Lord is Allah Who created the **heavens and the *earth* in six Days**, then established Himself on the Throne, conducting every affair. None can intercede except by His permission. That is Allah—your Lord, so worship Him ˹alone˺. Will you not then be mindful?
>
> 10:3

> It is Allah Who has created seven heavens and of the **earth the like thereof (i.e. seven)**. His Command descends between them (heavens and earth), that you may know that Allah has power over all things, and that Allah surrounds (comprehends) all things in (His) Knowledge.
>
> 65:12

So in verse number 10:3 it seems to imply that Allah created 7 heavens and 1 earth, but in verse number 65:12 it implies that Allah created 7 heavens and 7 earths.

Is that a contradiction, or it just looks like a controdiction but in reality it is not a contradiction but a misunderstanding of the verse(s).

Comment: And where is the contradiction? One Verse focuses on the earth we are leaving on. While the second gives an information that goes beyond this focus.

Comment: 10:3 it is saying that Allah created 7 heaven and earth(1) and in second it is say that Allah created 7 heaven and 7 earths. That is something I can not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear indication anywhere in the Quran regarding the number of earths, and 65:12 is subject to interpretation, although the most apparent meaning is that there are seven earths.

That interpretation is not contrary to the expression used in the Quran (  السماوات والأرض )  , because a singular can be used to refer to a group or to its genus, for example "man" is used to refer to all humans:

> خلق **الإنسان** من علق
>
> Created **man** from a clinging substance.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 96:2](http://quran.com/96/2)</sup>

> إن **الإنسان** لفي خسر إلا الذين آمنوا وعملوا الصالحات
>
> Verily **man** is in loss, Except those who believe and do righteous good deeds
>
> <sup>— [Quran 103:2-3](https://quran.com/103/2-3?translations=203)</sup>

It is known that there is not just one man but there are and have been billions. And these verses mean all the humans, not just one man.

In the same way when one mentions the 'earth' they may refer to all the earths and it is not necessary to separately mention their number or the fact that they are more than one.

---

**Reference:**

> والعرب قد تذكر الواحد بلفظ الجمع، والجمع بلفظ الواحد
>
> The Arabs may mention a single instance using a plural word, or may mention a group using a singular word
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Sam'ani](https://al-maktaba.org/book/8320/2256.)</sup>

For a list of other examples see works such as: [البرهان في علوم القرآن](https://ia800508.us.archive.org/34/items/FP3565/02_3566.pdf#page=233) and [المدخل لعلم تفسير كتاب الله تعالى](https://ia902706.us.archive.org/17/items/WAQ51965/51965.pdf#page=131) etc.